# Is it safe in terms of security when uploading files to amazon s3 via http not the https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, https

Is it safe in terms of security when uploading files to amazon s3 via http not the https?
I'm using curl on ubuntu.

When I tested to upload via https, It's slower then via http. It's about 3 times.
I don't know why but I'm guessing It happens cause company's proxy.

So I want to upload http instead of https. but I'm not sure It's safe or not.
Please help me.
thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it's not safe. Don't use unencrypted HTTP to upload private data.

Comment: If you have environment variables (or something else) setting a proxy for HTTPS but not HTTP, that might explain the difference in speed. e.g. if you have `HTTPS_PROXY` set, but not `HTTP_PROXY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not safe, and its **not a good practice**. What's more you should **enforce** any uploads to S3 to be https, which is **good practice** as explained in [Enforce encryption of data in transit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/security-best-practices.html#transit):

> You can use HTTPS (TLS) to help **prevent potential attackers from eavesdropping on or manipulating network traffic using person-in-the-middle or similar attacks**. You should allow only encrypted connections over HTTPS (TLS) using the aws:SecureTransport condition on Amazon S3 bucket policies.

Comment: Well I agree with your opinion.
Could you have an idea why http upload is faster than https about 3times?

Comment: @shfshfdl There is no encryption involved at all. But the difference is definitively no 3x in general. This must be something else wrong with your system.